# Set color of multiple materials on an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object that has multiple materials (count of 3-4) and I would like to set the color of all those materials the same. How do I do this?

```
myObj.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is [.material](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) but also [.materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html)

```
Material[] materials = myObj.materials;
for(int i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++)
{ 
    materials[i].SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
}
myObj.materials = materials;
```

As @derHugo pointed out, you need to clean up those materials if you destroy the object, like in [OnDestroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html)

If you want to apply the color-change to **all** objects using these materials, then [sharedMaterial](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterials.html) is your friend (same Behaviour as editing a material in the Inspector):

```
Material[] sharedMaterials = myObj.sharedMaterials;
for(int i = 0; i < sharedMaterials.Length; i++)
{ 
    sharedMaterials[i].SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
}
myObj.sharedMaterials = sharedMaterials;
```

Same procedure, but you don't need to clean up, but it changes all instances.

There is also [MaterialPropertyBlocks](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) which can be useful, especially in combination with DrawMeshInstanced (when you want to have a TON of objects with different colors)

Comment: you should cache the result of `myObj.materials`, also note `This function automatically instantiates the materials and makes them unique to this renderer. It is your responsibility to destroy the materials when the game object is being destroyed`